# Laravel Cashier (Stripe) - Product Checkout - Important events

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

When working with Cashier Stripe Checkout within my Laravel 10 app, what events do I need to listen to when it comes to an existing product that has been created within the Stripe dashboard?

The app will operate in EU, requring 3Ds for the payments. I tried to go through the docs from Stripe, and it seems that the only imporant event is `checkout.session.completed`. I assume that it's not a good idea to strictly rely only on the `success_url` / `cancel_url`, but one event also seems to not be enough. All I need to do is for the user to be able to buy a specific training session, and if the payment is successful, I want to make a reservation for him.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-The `success_url` is the page your customer is redirected to once they *successfully* complete the Session.
-The `cancel_url` is the page your customer is redirected to if they press the 'back' arrow on the Session. It's optional - if you don't set one your Session will have no 'back' arrow.
-If the information fails to validate, or the payment is declined, then you customer stays on the Session - the error is displayed in session.

This means that `checkout.session.completed` could be the only event you care about - since it would be ubiquitous with a success.
There is one exception : async payment method types.

For EU payments, this means SEPA DD and Sofort [Edit=also Bacs if your account is UK]. Those payment method types are async, meaning the payment is 'pending' for a while after the customer completes the Session, and could still fail afterwards.

Stripe triggers the `checkout.session.async_payment_failed` and `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` events for these scenarios.
The payments would still trigger a `checkout.session.completed` event initially, however you can recognize them by the attribute `payment_status=unpaid`.

Related guide:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#delayed-notification

EDIT= one quick clarification - 3DS authentication (or any other type or payment authentication) does not fall under those async payment types (even though you could argue it's an async process). Authentication modals are presented in Session, and the customer stays in session if this authentication fails.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. All I need to have is a simple one time payment using a credit/debit cards where the 3DS is required, so if the checkout.session.completed is only fired when the payment is successful, this is most probably the only thing I need to listen to.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to listen to any events, because Cashier already has a webhook handler that will create subscriptions in your database if a user completes a Stripe checkout session.

Comment: This pre-built webhook handler covers only the subscriptions right? For me, it's only a one time non-reccuring payments, so I think this wouldn't help me. All I need to do is to make sure that the payment was successful.

Comment: I initially wanted to use the subscriptions, but since the membership should not be reccuring, I would need to cancel it right after the payment, which would not make much sense. Also, within the Stripe Checkout, anchorBillingCycleOn is not supported, so I would have to use the trial if the user decides that the membership should start later, which would be kinda misleading for the users.

Comment: Would have been good to clarify you weren’t talking about subscriptions in your question in that case. Yes, you can define a listener and listen for `checkout.session.completed` event. I do this in an app where customers can rent videos for a predetermined length of time.